# How to send frequent real-time server-side status update messages?

Tags: web-services, webserver, websocket

I have a web server that listens for jQuery keyboard events and I would like to send a string of the status for a set of keys to another domain for processing.

What technology/language/protocol is able to do this on the server-side?

It must be able to send the updated status message upon immediate change as listened for by keyboard events like arrow keys.

This is not a standard server <-> client updating but rather client > server > another server.

Can a WebSocket be used to create a server-side connection to a remote location, not a client?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets

Comment: [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki) seems to fit your description. The intermediate server will be the "client" that forwards whatever it receives to your final server.

Comment: there are many frameworks available. The communication pattern is called "push". Be aware of HTML5 features : there are not all implemented in the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

> What technology/language/protocol is able to do this on the server-side?

Any modern server side language can do it, node.js, c#, python, php. Just write your condition and make the request from your server as client.

> Can a WebSocket be used to create a server-side connection to a remote location, not a client?

Of course! Your server can be a client like any other device. [NodeJS example](http://Can%20a%20WebSocket%20be%20used%20to%20create%20a%20server-side%20connection%20to%20a%20remote%20location,%20not%20a%20client?)